# checked bags from Singapore

Tags: luggage, check-in, singapore-airlines

I am flying out from Singapore to London Heathrow on Singapore Airlines.  I will arrive Heathrow at 15.20.  My next flight out from Heathrow to Raleigh, NC USA is on the next morning at 10.00am with American Airlines. My question is:

Can I tag my bags all the way from Singapore to Raleigh? If not, what are my options?  I prefer not to clear my bags and recheck them the next morning.  Thanks much for your advise.

Comment: Did you buy the itinerary on a single booking?

Comment: Of possible related interest: *[Can I check through my luggage on a flight with a long (~1d) stopover, combining two different airlines on one ticket?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67188)* and *[What happens to checked luggage when there's an overnight layover?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30442)*